# Laravel DB query with count

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query where i need to use count and have a normal query.

Normal

```
select sum(total) as Total,AffID,user_id from Affiliates 
group by AffID order by user_id ASC
```

And Then

```
foreach($result_array as $row) 
{ 
    echo $row['total']."<br/>"; 
    echo $row['AffID']."<br/>"; 
    echo $row['user_id ']."<br/>"; 
}
```

In Laravel i have tried

```
$affdata = DB::select('Affiliates')
         ->whereRaw('CompletedDate >= curdate()')
         ->groupBy('AffID')
         ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
         ->sum('total');
         ->get();
foreach($affdata as $row) 
{
   echo $row->AffID ."<br>";
   echo $row->total ."<br>";
}
```

But it seems to throw out an error. As i need to echo out the AFFID along with calculating the Total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct query

```
$affdata = DB::table('Affiliates')->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total'), 'AffID', 'user_id')
            ->whereRaw('CompletedDate >= curdate()')
            ->groupBy('AffID')
            ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your query to this.

```
$affdata = DB::table('Affiliates')->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total'), 'AffID', 'user_id'))
            ->whereRaw('CompletedDate >= curdate()')
            ->groupBy('AffID')
            ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
            ->sum('total');
            ->get();
```